# Image fill in div (ruby)?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

it might be simple question.

i have a image-box/div that i want it to be fill in completely by image, all kind random sizes of images will be fit in the div.

at the moment, it just follow the height of the div, which is 200px. but the width of the image is not reaching the edge of the div.

how do i make image to expand proportionally and fit inside the div?

thank you in advance.

[the tour box, the image div is on left part of the tour box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlLHm.png)

```
<section class="tours">
<div class="container">

    <% @tours.each do | tour |%>
    <div class="tours-box">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 tours-image-box">

                    <%= image_tag tour.tourimage.url ()%>

            </div>

            <!-- Description -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 tours-description-box ">
                <div class="box-inner">
                    <div class="tours-description">

                    <h4><span><%= image_tag tour.tour_category.icon.url(:thumb) %></span><%= tour.title %></h4>
                    <p><%= tour.text %></p>

                    <div class="tours-indicator">
                        <h6>Capacity: <%= "#{remain_capacity(tour)}" %> / <%=tour.capacity%> remaining</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Price --> 
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="box-inner">
                    <div class="tours-price">
                        <ul>
                            <li><h6>RM <span class="price-value"><%= tour.price_for_adult %></span><span class="price-type"> /adult</span></h6></li>
                            <li><h6>RM <span class="price-value"><%= tour.price_for_child %></span><span class="price-type"> /child</span></h6></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="button-text date">Check Date</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <% tour_id = "tour-id-#{tour.id}" %>
                        <button class="btn button button-outline" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%= tour_id %>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<%= tour_id %>">View More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="<%= tour_id %>">
        <div class="tours-more">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Star Time & Duration -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="more-box">
                        <div class="more-details">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h6>Start Time:</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p><%= tour.try(:start_time).try(:strftime,"%H:%M %P") %></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="more-details">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h6>Duration:</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p><%= tour.duration %></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            <!-- Activities & Location -->    
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="more-box">
                    <div class="more-details">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h6>Activity:</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p><span class="activities-icon"><%= image_tag tour.tour_category.icon.url(:thumb) %></span><%= tour.tour_category %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="more-details">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h6>Location:</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p><%= tour.location %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Notes -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="more-box">
                        <h6>Notes:</h6>
                        <p><%= tour.notes %></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Decision -->    
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="more-box">
                    <div class="tours-decision">
                    <a href="#" class="favourite button-text">Favourite This</a>
                    <!--
                    <ul>
                        <li class="subtext">Share This</li>
                        <li><span><%= image_tag("host-detail-airport.png", alt: "Airport") %></span>on FacebooK</li>
                        <li><span><%= image_tag("host-detail-airport.png", alt: "Airport") %></span>on Twitter</li>

                    </ul>
                    -->
                    <div class="share">
                        <%= render 'layouts/socialshare' %>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn button button-wide">Book This</button>
                        </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

css

```
.tours {
background-color: $halfwhite;
padding: 32px 0px;
.tours-box {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid $bluedark;
    margin-top: 20px;

    .box-inner {
        border-left: 2px solid $bluedark;
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    .tours-image-box {
        padding-right: 0px;


            img {
                position: relative;
                object-fit: cover;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                margin: auto;
                height: 200px;
                max-width: 100%;
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about changing the CSS line `max-width: 100%` to `width: 100%` ? It should fit the entire parent `div`. You can also create a specific CSS class for this case, like

```
.fit-image{
  width: 100%;
}
```

And your  `image_tag` in ruby:

```
<%= image_tag(tour.tour_category.icon.url(:thumb), class: 'fit-image') %>
```

Comment: thanks samir, it works! i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

You have:

```
<%= image_tag tour.tourimage.url ()%>
```

You may want to try the following example:

```
<%= image_tag 'example.jpg', class: 'img-responsive center-block' %>
```

Comment: Thanks benny for your input.